# onnx2keras error in conversion from onnx to keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, onnx

I'm trying to import an onnx model and convert it to keras.

Below there is the snippet of code I'm using:

```
import onnx
import onnxmltools
import onnx2keras
from onnx2keras import onnx_to_keras

onnx_model = onnxmltools.utils.load_model('gdrive/My Drive/Model/MLP_Heart_comfort_model.onnx')
k_model = onnx_to_keras(onnx_model, ['dense_1_input'], name_policy='renumerate')
```

The error I get is the following:

```
INFO:onnx2keras:Converter is called.
DEBUG:onnx2keras:List input shapes:
DEBUG:onnx2keras:None
DEBUG:onnx2keras:List inputs:
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Input 0 -> dense_1_input.
DEBUG:onnx2keras:List outputs:
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Output 0 -> dense_6.
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Gathering weights to dictionary.
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_6/kernel:0 with shape (8, 2).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_6/bias:0 with shape (2,).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_5/kernel:0 with shape (32, 8).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_5/bias:0 with shape (8,).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_4/kernel:0 with shape (256, 32).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_4/bias:0 with shape (32,).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_3/kernel:0 with shape (1024, 256).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_3/bias:0 with shape (256,).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_2/kernel:0 with shape (1024, 1024).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_2/bias:0 with shape (1024,).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_1/kernel:0 with shape (8, 1024).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found weight dense_1/bias:0 with shape (1024,).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found input dense_1_input with shape [8]
DEBUG:onnx2keras:######
DEBUG:onnx2keras:...
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Converting ONNX operation
DEBUG:onnx2keras:type: MatMul
DEBUG:onnx2keras:node_name: transformed_tensor5
DEBUG:onnx2keras:node_params: {'change_ordering': False, 'name_policy': 'renumerate'}
DEBUG:onnx2keras:...
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Check if all inputs are available:
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Check input 0 (name dense_1_input).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Check input 1 (name dense_1/kernel:0).
DEBUG:onnx2keras:The input not found in layers / model inputs.
DEBUG:onnx2keras:Found in weights, add as a numpy constant.
DEBUG:onnx2keras:... found all, continue
DEBUG:onnx2keras:gemm:Convert GEMM without bias.
DEBUG:onnx2keras:gemm:Input units 8, output units 1024.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-6b7516d3c793> in <module>()
      5 
      6 onnx_model = onnxmltools.utils.load_model('gdrive/My Drive/Model/MLP_Heart_comfort_model.onnx')
----> 7 k_model = onnx_to_keras(onnx_model, ['dense_1_input'], name_policy='renumerate') # steril: dense_7_input  heart: dense_1_input

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnx2keras/converter.py in onnx_to_keras(onnx_model, input_names, input_shapes, name_policy, verbose, change_ordering)
    184             keras_names = keras_names[0]
    185 
--> 186         logger.debug('Output TF Layer -> ' + str(layers[keras_names]))
    187 
    188     # Check for terminal nodes

KeyError: 'LAYER_0'
```

I've been working with this piece of code for a long time and everything, until a couple of days ago, worked fine.

Today I tried to execute it and I get that error.

Anyone could help me out with that?